# algolia facets returns empty object in javascript API client

Tags: algolia

I'm using the Javascript API [Client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js) and would like to have facets return on my index. I believe faceting is turned on for the index because 1. I toggled the switch in the UI 2. I can use faceting in the dashboard for my index. I set up my index with the following params:

```
var params = {
  tagFilters: 'query',
  aroundLatLngViaIP: true,
  getRankingInfo: 1,
  facets: "*"
};
```

However, this returns an empty facets object. How can I receive a facet object with all possible faceting options?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fb3fdfzn/)

Comment: Hi, can you provide the full working code example? Thanks

Comment: @vvo added JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fb3fdfzn/ (with updated fiddle)

Comment: @vvo I figured out what's going on. There are no available facets on the specific searches I was doing. Once I changed the query to "Eye Doctor" it returned. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no result for this query, hence the lack of facet.
You can maybe see it more easily on [this updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfc8zwuj/4/):

```js
index.search(params).then(function(resp) {
  count.innerText = resp.hits.length + ' results';
  facets.innerText = JSON.stringify(resp.facets, null, 2);
  response.innerText = JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2);
});
```